# Text aligns incorrectly in HTML input. What to change in my code?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, textbox

I'm making an HTML form for writing posts.
I was able to create and resize the text input and set a new width & height.
However, the article cannot be properly written due to its position inside the text box. It's in the middle of it, not at the top.

[image: Wrong text position]

Here's an HTML code:

```
<form id="newpost" action="action.php" method="post">
    <input id="post" type="text" placeholder="Type here..." name="article">
    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

CSS code:

```
#newpost {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 14px;
}
#post {
    float: left;
    width: 250%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#submit {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 402px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #dedede;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Whenever I type, the text always appears in the middle of the text box.
How can I make it appear at the top? And how can I make the text to automatically jump to the next row if the previous one is full. It's infinite right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<textarea>` instead of `<input>` like this:

```
<textarea id="post" type="text" placeholder="Type here..." name="article"></textarea>
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/42/

Comment: I totally forgot about the <textarea>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For multi-line text entry, you need [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) not an `<input>`

```
<form id="newpost" action="action.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="post" type="text" placeholder="Type here..." name="article"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about the <textarea>. Completely forgot about it.